# Python Combination Generator - Store to .txt file

Tags: python, file, combinations

So basically, i have a combination generator script... and it works... the way it works is it generates the combinations and then i copy/paste them into a text file, well thats hard considering for 6 digits there 1.4billion permutations.. and also after about 1.3million it crahses? so how do i make it so when it makes a combination it stores it to the .txt file, and if it crashes... it can restart from the last recorded line in the .txt file
script:

```
import itertools
from itertools import *

lower_a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',  'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
num = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

all = []
all = lower_a + num

def com():
    for x in range(2):
        for s in itertools.product(all, repeat=x):
            print(''.join(s))

print(com())
```

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that you really do need a file containing all 1.4 billion permutations? Are you really, really sure?

Comment: How long does it take to do the 1.3m? If you change the code to just `''.join(s)` without printing that, does it still crash after that amount of time? Also, you don't need to import `itertools` into two namespaces - I'd just stick with the first one (which you're using) and get rid of `from itertools import *`.

Comment: it says in output window 'None'

Comment: It's saying `None` because you don't have a `return` statement, so it returns the default `None`. If you're running it from the interactive interpreter instead of a saved script, it'll show you that returned value.

Comment: Did it run with high CPU for a while, and then spit out `None`?

Comment: Oh I see, you `print` it - and it returns `None`, so it will certainly print that.

Comment: Try this: change it back to `print(''.join(s))`, change `print(com())` to just `com()`, and run your script with something like `py myscript.py | myresults.txt`. Caution: the file will be huge, and all that HDD I/O will take a long time.

Comment: how would it put it to a file? and how would i run it with py myscript.py... ive only use(d) the run module in python

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - use `>`, not `|`. Just call your script from the command line and redirect the output to a file. `py myscript.py > myresults.txt`.

Comment: Why not use `itertools.permutations` directly?

Comment: The code you have displayed is not the code that you are running.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have displayed is not the code that you are running. For example this segment can't behave as you describe:

```
for x in range(2):
    for s in itertools.product(all, repeat=x):
        print(''.join(s))
```

This should display the Cartesian product for members of all under two conditions:

- when x is 0
- when x is 1

When x is zero `itertools.product(any_list_at_all, repeat=0)` has only one combination of zero elements, which is the empty set. When z is one, the number of combinations is equal to the length of the input list. In your case, this makes a total of `len(all)` combinations of 36 characters taken 1 at a time which is 36 sets.

Since in a Cartesian product, the cardinality of the output set is the product of the cardinalities of the input set (for finite sets), which means that `product(all, range=6)` has about 2.2 billion sets returned, so where does 1.4 billion come from?

Comment: Probably 36*35*34*33*32*31 (=1,402,410,240).

Comment: It does say *"1.4billion permutations"*.